# Attempted relative import with no known parent package import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, directory

I'm running on python 3.8 with Windows 10.

I have the following structure of directories:

```
Selenium
|   functions.py
|   folder1
|    |   folder2
|    |    |   folder3
|    |    |    |    main.py
```

Inside the main.py file:

```
from ....functions import *
```

when I run the main.py file, I receive the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```